# How to put glyphicon on Asp.net Button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I want to put glyphicon to asp.net Button but the icon is not showing, there is no error and the class is added but not showing up. I don't want LinkButton or html server. Is there anyone already accomplished this? thanks!

```
      <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-save" runat="server" Width="150px"
                  OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Comment: Works fine on my dev machine. Are you sure bootstrap is loaded? Check your browser console. Also use `CssClass` instead of `class`

Comment: what version of vs are you using? I'm using vs 2010 express. I tried cssclass but not working. anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-save">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save"  runat="server" Width="150px"
                  OnClick="btnSave_Click" />    
</div>
```

Comment: its somehow achieve what I want but I need to add class for the button, and fit exactly the button to the div, could you do that? thanks! i'll vote up because this kinda helpful.

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" CssClass="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-save"  runat="server" Width="150px"
                  OnClick="btnSave_Click" />    did you tried this way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-search">
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Search" BackColor="Transparent" BorderWidth="0" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue